# Plane Sweep Algorithm - points lying outside the disks

Tags: algorithm, math, computational-geometry

Let `D` is a set of `n` disjoint disks and `P` is a set of `n` points.

How can one design an `O(n*log(n))` plane sweep algorithm that reports each point in `P` lying outside all disks?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the points top to bottom and sort the disks by their top ordinate. The "active list" contains all disks that intersect the horizontal by the current point.

You will go from one point to the next, each time updating the active list (check for new entries, and for exits).

Then the current point is outside of all disks if it lies outside all disks in the active list.

Comment: This is a good start, but since the "active list" can potentially include all the disks at once, I think some extra work is needed in order to do the "if it lies outside all disks in the active list" check in O(log n) time. (Maybe maintain a copy of the active list that's ordered by abscissa?)

Comment: @ruakh: that's right, the disks should somehow be ordered horizontally. But this raises another issue: even is disjoint, the projections of the disks on an horizontal may overlap.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible for more than O(1) disjoint disks to all span a given x-coordinate *and* all span a given a y-coordinate? I can't tell offhand. (Geometry is not my strong suit!)

Comment: @ruakh: I can think of a situation such that one large disk overlaps with all others. My point was that there is no total ordering horizontally.

Comment: Re: "My point was that there is no total ordering horizontally": Agreed.